# Avoiding Squeryl transaction in Play! controllers

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

I am learning Play! and I have followed the [To do List tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaTodoList). Now, I would like to use Squeryl in place of Anorm, so I tried to translate the tutorial, and actually it works.

Still, there is one little thing that irks me. Here is the relevant part of my model

```
def all: Iterable[Task] = from(tasks) {s => select(s)}
```

and the corresponding action in the controller to list all tasks

```
def tasks = Action {
    inTransaction {
        Ok(views.html.index(Task.all, taskForm))
    }
}
```

The view contains, for instance

```
<h1>@tasks.size task(s)</h1>
```

What I do not like is that, unlike in the methods to update or delete tasks, I had to manage the transaction inside the controller action.

If I move `inTransaction` to the `all` method, I get an exception,

```
[RuntimeException: No session is bound to current thread, a session must be created via Session.create and bound to the thread via 'work' or 'bindToCurrentThread' Usually this error occurs when a statement is executed outside of a transaction/inTrasaction block]
```

because the view tries to obtain the size of `tasks`, but the transaction is already closed at that point.

> Is there a way to use Squeryl transaction only in the model and not expose these details up to the controller level?

Comment: Why don't you just convert the Iterable to a List in the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. It's because of lazy evaluations on Iterable that require session bound (size() method).
This might work if you turn Iterable into List or Vector (IndexedSeq) I suppose.

```
from(tasks)(s => select(s)).toIndexedSeq //or .toList
```

Comment: Along the same lines is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067425/squeryl-run-query-explicitly/11273250#11273250